# SQL job cannot delete snapshot

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue with deleting snapshot job. The SQL Server job history shows:

> Message Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. The step did not generate any output.  Process Exit Code 255.  The step failed.

`NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT` account has "full control" permissions to whole snapshot path.

My job has one step:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path G:\Data\snapshot\unc\SNAPSHOT_PUBLICATION -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
get-Date >> g:\data\snapshot\unc\snapshot-cleaner.log
```

Any ideas why this action fails every time?

Comment: Have you executed this script manually without error?

Comment: yes, I executed this job manually, but getting the same error

Comment: Manually as in directly in a Powershell window. Also does the SQL Server Agent Service user account have permissions on that folder (and it's not a mapped network drive)?

Comment: OK, i executed it from powershell ISE and it works. NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT has full control on that folder. Folder is shared, cause I have second server for data replication.